# How to refer a equation written inside a item in enumerate in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, enumerate

I want to refer to an equation written inside the enumerate.

```
\section{}\label{}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item   \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
         a + b = c \eqref{eq:1}
        \end{equation} 

       \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
         a + d = e \eqref{eq:2}
       \end{equation}

\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

But this results in

```
a + b = c    (2)
a + d = e    (2)
```

just (2) for both the equations as it the item number inside the enumerate which contains the equation. What I want is atleast (2.1) or (2.2) or better would be

```
a + b = c    (3.6.2.1)
a + d = e    (3.6.2.2)
```

(Chapter.section.item.1 ) and (Chapter.section.item.2 ) .

I also want to refer to this equation later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a compilable code?

Comment: Works fine here in `article`/`report`, both equation number and reference are correct, so to work out what is wrong you would need to make a complete example that demonstrates the problem. (By the way, `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, assuming you have `\usepackage{amsmath}`, will give equation numbers `chapter.section.equation`.)

Comment: it's very peculiar to have both a label and `\eqref` referring to that same label within the same equation.  the `equation` environment alone should produce a printed equation number, and `\eqref` is meant to be used outside that environment, in text referring to the equation.  (there are other peculiarities, but without a compilable example, trying to say anything more would just be guessing.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the enumerate index in the equation number, you can use the following (unless you also use a package which replaces the enumi counter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\section{}\label{}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theenumi.\arabic{equation}}%
\item
\item  \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
         a + b = c \eqref{eq:1}
        \end{equation} 

       \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
         a + d = e \eqref{eq:2}
       \end{equation}

\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```